# Thumbnail Image From Youtube

Tags: iphone, ios6, youtube, uiimage

I want to create thumbnail image from youtube url. I am trying thumbnailImageAtTime method but cant able to create thumbnail image. Please Help me.

Here is my code:

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02Bzjj1eeeo"]];

UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
[imgview setImage:thumbnail];
[player stop];
```

Comment: are you sure you are going to get video from the url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02Bzjj1eeeo

Comment: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/

Comment: this is image you want to set http://img.youtube.com/vi/02Bzjj1eeeo/1.jpg

Comment: use my latest comment url to see your url image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way is to get the frame of the video and use that image frame with that youtube url:

```
NSString *urlStringImage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://img.youtube.com/vi/%@/1.jpg",idOfYoutubeVideo];
NSData thumbnailImageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStringImage]];
```

Eg: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8cJKirMo-A

video id = K8cJKirMo-A

urlStringImage = http://img.youtube.com/vi/**K8cJKirMo-A**/default.jpg

use default.png instead of 1.jpg

Comment: tried but gives default image only, need to ask can we play youtube video directly just copy pasting the url. I don't think so, if so we can easily make an youtube downloader.

Comment: no you can not direct play. try LBYoutubeplayer. it will do streaming. You can find the sample code on github

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve it easily by using below youtube api url
“http://img.youtube.com/vi/” + youtubeVideoID + “/default.jpg”

for more details, check this link [blogfornet-youtube thumbnail](http://blogfornet.com/2013/10/how-to-retrieve-youtube-thumbnail-in-asp-net/).